# Remove duplicates within consecutive runs of characters

Tags: r, regex, indexing

I have strings containing lots of duplicates, like this:

```
tst <- c("C>C>C>B>B>B>B>C>C>*>*>*>*>*>C", "A>A>A", "*>B>B", 
     "A>A>A>A>A>*>A>A>A>*>*>*>*>A>A", "*>C>C", "A")
```

I'd like to remove all **consecutive duplicated upper-case and "*"** characters, so the expected result is this:

```
[1] "CBC*C" "A"     "*B"    "A*A*A" "*C"    "A"
```

I've successfully extracted the duplicated capitals:

```
library(stringr)
unlist(str_extract_all(gsub(">", "", tst), "(.)(?=\\1)"))
[1] "C" "C" "B" "B" "B" "C" "*" "*" "*" "*"
```

but am somewhat stuck here. My hunch is that the function `which`, which returns indices, might be of help but don't know how to implement it in this case.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**:

I wasn't that far from the solution myself - just using a *negative* lookahead (instead of the positive lookahead) does the trick:

```
str_extract_all(gsub(">", "", tst), "(.)(?!\\1)")
[[1]]
[1] "C" "B" "C" "*" "C"

[[2]]
[1] "A"

[[3]]
[1] "*" "B"

[[4]]
[1] "A" "*" "A" "*" "A"

[[5]]
[1] "*" "C"

[[6]]
[1] "A"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `gsub`

```
gsub("([A-Z*]>)\\1+", "\\1", tst)
#[1] "C>B>C>*>C"
```

In order to get the second result, remove the `>`

```
gsub(">", "", gsub("([A-Z*]\\>)\\1+", "\\1", tst) ,fixed = TRUE)
#[1] "CBC*C"
```

Based on the OP's comments below, may be

```
gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub(">", "", tst))
#[1] "CBC*C"
gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub(">", "", "A>"))
#[1] "A"
gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub(">", "", "A>A"))
#[1] "A"
gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub(">", "", "A>A>A>A"))
#[1] "A"
```

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann What is the expected for that

Comment: `A` just that, nothing else

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann this returns that `gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub(">", "", "A>A>A>A"))#
[1] "A"` testing on `gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub(">", "", tst))#
[1] "CBC*C"`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann this also works with `gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub(">", "", "A>A"))#
[1] "A"` compared to `gsub("((.)>)\\1+\\2*", "\\2", "A>A")#
[1] "A>A"`

Answer (score 3):

Another way to get `CBC*C` could be using 2 groups and using group 2 in the replacement.

```
((.)>)\1+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oeuVA8/1)

Example

```
tst <- "C>C>C>B>B>B>B>C>C>*>*>*>*>*>C"
gsub("((.)>)\\1+", "\\2", tst)
```

Output

```
[1] "CBC*C"
```

Comment: This is a beautiful solution.

Comment: Why does the solution fail on something like this: `gsub("((.)>)\\1+", "\\2", "A>A>A>A")`? How could it be edited to work for this type of case too?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann That depends on what the expected result is. The current pattern repeats the capture group to get the consecutive parts. The replacement uses the inner second group.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann it does not match the last A because it is not in the repeating pattern. You could optionally match the second group `((.)>)\1+\2*`  to match the same trailing character(s). https://regex101.com/r/CldbL6/1

Comment: This works fine for me: `gsub("((.))\\1+", "\\2", gsub(">", "", tst))`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann The result is `A` indeed. Note that it also works for `>>>>>>>A` because you first remove all `>` and then replace remaining consecutive A's to a single A. You could reduce that to a single capture group `gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub(">", "", tst))`

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann If the `>` does not have to be present, this pattern would also work `((.)>?)\1+` https://regex101.com/r/ttcTh0/1 See https://ideone.com/7Rq2rF

Comment: Thanks a lot. The best solution, it turns out, is indeed `gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", gsub(">", "", tst))`. @akrun posted it just a few minutes earlier. So for fairness I'll have to accept his answer.

Answer (score 2):

For us allergic to regex:

```
paste(rle(strsplit(tst, ">")[[1]])$values, collapse = ">") # or collapse = ""
[1] "C>B>C>*>C"
```

...which of course fails for strings with runs of *lowercase letters*, like `"A>A>a>a>A>A"`

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat universal **base R** approach without regexps.

The idea here is to melt down the string to groups and then remove the repeating patterns successively (which makes it distinct from `unique`):

```
tst <- "C>C>C>B>B>B>B>C>C>*>*>*>*>*>C"
st <- paste(unlist(strsplit(tst,">")),collapse="")
#[1] "CCCBBBBCC*****C"

paste( unlist( sapply( 1:nchar(st), function(x){
  if( substr(st,x,x) != substr(st,(x+1),(x+1)) ){ substr(st,x,x) } } ) ), collapse="" )
#[1] "CBC*C"
```

Oh, and if you want lowercase functionality (excluding lowercase letters from removal), use this instead:

```
paste( unlist( sapply( 1:nchar(st), function(x){
  a=substr(st,x,x); b=substr(st,(x+1),(x+1));
  if( a != b & toupper(a) == a ){ a } else if( toupper(a) != a ){ a }  } ) ), collapse="" )
```