# Remove run-length duplicate numbers and NA in strings

Tags: r, regex, duplicates

I have columns with large strings of decimal numbers and `NA`:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A_gsr =c("2.752,2.752,2.752,2.752,2.752,2.752,2.752,2.911,2.911,3.555",
           "2.999,2.999,2.999,2.752,2.752,2.752,2.752"),
  B_gsr = c("1.34,1.34,1.34,1.55,1.55,1.55,1.55,1.55,1.55,1.55",
            "1.56,1.56,1.56,1.55,1.55,1.55,1.55,NA,NA,NA,NA,1.34,1.34,1.34"),
  C_gsr = c("NA,NA,NA,0.147,0.147,0.147,0.147,0.147,NA",
            "0.146,0.146,0.146,0.146,0.146,0.146,0.146,0.146,0.146,0.146")
)
```

I want to remove all run-length duplicates. Using `gsub` and backreference, I'm getting pretty close to what I want to have:

```
lapply(df[,1:3], function(x) gsub("((\\d\\.\\d+,)|(NA,))\\1+", "\\1", x))
$A_gsr
[1] "2.752,2.911,3.555" "2.999,2.752,2.752"

$B_gsr
[1] "1.34,1.55,1.55"         "1.56,1.55,NA,1.34,1.34"

$C_gsr
[1] "NA,0.147,NA" "0.146,0.146"
```

However, not close enough - there are still some run-length dups, all at the end of the strings. The **expected result** is this:

```
$A_gsr
[1] "2.752,2.911,3.555" "2.999,2.752"

$B_gsr
[1] "1.34,1.55"         "1.56,1.55,NA,1.34"

$C_gsr
[1] "NA,0.147,NA" "0.146"
```

Comment: For a non-regex alternative, my "single-column" answer here [Remove duplicates within consecutive runs of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66355525/1851712) will work with quite minor modifications. `l = strsplit(x, ",")`; `lapply(l, function(s) paste(rle(s)$values, collapse = ","))` (lapply this over columns)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```r
lapply(df[,1:3], function(x) gsub("\\b(\\d+\\.\\d+|NA)(?:,\\1)+\\b", "\\1", x))
## => $A_gsr
##   [1] "2.752,2.911,3.555" "2.999,2.752"      
##   
##   $B_gsr
##   [1] "1.34,1.55"         "1.56,1.55,NA,1.34"
##   
##   $C_gsr
##   [1] "NA,0.147,NA" "0.146"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7hnqQf/1) and the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/HaeslM).

*Details*:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(\d+\.\d+|NA)` - Group 1: one or more digits, `.`, one or more digits, OR `NA` string
- `(?:,\1)+` - one or more repetitions of a comma and the value in Group 1
- `\b` - a word boundary

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one question: is it really necessary to use `\\b`? The code seems to work without too.

Comment: Maybe an alternative: `lapply(df, function(x) gsub("\\b([^,]*)(,\\1)+\\b", "\\1", x))`

Comment: @GKi yes, brilliant. Post it so I can upvote it.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann If all the numbers follow the same format (i.e. 1 digit before `.` and 3 digits after `.`, there is no need to use word boundaries. But it is best practice, so I am using it.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann If you want to shorten it as you are not interested in "pre-validation" (checking it is a number or `NA`), you may just use `"\\b([\\w.]+)(?:,\\1)+\\b"` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/7hnqQf/3)) or even `"(.+?)(?:,\\1)+"` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/7hnqQf/2)) (since you do not need word boundaries here.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I have just exchanged the part testing for numbers or NA. So its nothing new in this alternative.