# How to extract unique letters among word of consecutive letters?

Tags: r, string, unique

For example, there is character `x = "AAATTTGGAA"`.

What I want to achieve is, from `x`, split `x` by consecutive letters, `"AAA", "TTT", "GG", "AA"`.

Then, unique letters of each chunk is `"A", "T", "G", "A"` , so expected output is `ATGA`.

How should I get this?

Comment: Related: [Remove duplicates within consecutive runs of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66355324/remove-duplicates-within-consecutive-runs-of-characters)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a useful regex trick approach:

```r
x <- "AAATTTGGAA"
out <- strsplit(x, "(?<=(.))(?!\\1)", perl=TRUE)[[1]]
out

[1] "AAA" "TTT" "GG"  "AA"
```

The regex pattern used here says to split at any boundary where the preceding and following characters are different.

```regex
(?<=(.))  lookbehind and also capture preceding character in \1
(?!\\1)   then lookahead and assert that following character is different
```

Answer (score 4):

You can split each character in the string. Use `rle` to find consecutive runs and select only the unique ones.

```
x <- "AAATTTGGAA"
vec <- unlist(strsplit(x, ''))

rle(vec)$values
#[1] "A" "T" "G" "A"

paste0(rle(vec)$values, collapse = '')
#[1] "ATGA"
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use `regmatch` with pattern `(.)\\1+` like below

```
> regmatches(x,gregexpr("(.)\\1+",x))[[1]]
[1] "AAA" "TTT" "GG"  "AA"
```

or if you need the unique letters only

```
> gsub("(.)\\1+", "\\1", x)
[1] "ATGA"
```